# How to get UIImagePicker selected image name?

Tags: ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

Does anyone know how to get the selected image name (the one from photo gallery) after presenting an UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of [ALAsset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ALAsset) you can able to achieve this.

Step 1: Get the `Asset` for the selected Image from the `UIImagePicker`

Step 2: Get the [ALAssetRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that `Asset`.

Step 3: `ALAssetRepresentation` class has a property called `fileName`

```
- (NSString *)filename
```

Returns a string representing the filename of the representation on disk.

This Sample Code will Helps you...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        NSString *fileName = [representation filename];
        NSLog(@"fileName : %@",fileName);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageURL 
                   resultBlock:resultblock
                  failureBlock:nil];

}
```

NOTE: It works only in **iOS 5** and later.

Comment: 3 months before I have searched for my project, but I didn't got any idea regarding iOS 5 and lesser.

Comment: hi im use this code but i dnt know to - (NSString *)filename i got error NSString *fileName = [representation filename]; in this line how to use this code help me

Comment: @Shalini : have you found the solution?

Comment: No dont get solution my error Definition of 'ALAssetRepresenation' must br imported from from module 'AssetsLibrary.ALAssetRepresentation' before  it is required

Comment: @Shalini  in your .h class paste this line `@import AssetsLibrary;` and `ALAssetRepresentation` works perfectly.