# I have selected an image using imagepicker from my phone gallery.how can i retrieve the name of that selected image?

Tags: ios, iphone

my code for selecting the image is below.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageview.image = chosenImage;
    NSLog(@"%@",chosenImage);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UIImagePicker selected image name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471254/how-to-get-uiimagepicker-selected-image-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: i want to load this selected image into an image view in my next view controller.i saved this image name into coredata.how can i load this image?