# How can i retrieve an image filename using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to know how to retrieve the filename of an image taken with the camera using UIImagePickerController.

I don't need to do anything with it, i just have to display the filename, like something you would see when you attach a file when you're sending an email.

So far, i'm using AssetsLibrary :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
        NSLog(@"[imageRep filename] : %@", [imageRep filename]);
        self.photoNameLabel.text = [imageRep filename];
    };

    // get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];


    self.photoLoaded = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

But `imageAsset` will always be `nil` if it comes from the device camera, and if not, the image is named IMG_00XX.jpg, even if i downloaded it from the internet before, with a different name.

Can i get the name of a picture in an ios environment? If so, how am i supposed to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get UIImagePicker selected image name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471254/how-to-get-uiimagepicker-selected-image-name)

Comment: @DipenPanchasara That duplicate doesn't apply here. This question is about taking a photo with the camera, not selecting a picture from the photo library.

Answer (score 1):

There is no name when you take a photo with the camera. All there is is the in-memory `UIImage` instance. It's not associated with a file.

If you wish to add this camera image to an email as an attachment, give it whatever name you want such as "photo.jpg" or "picture.jpg" or anything else you wish to use.

Comment: Good to know. And is it possible to get the "real name" of a downloaded image? So far, i think ios is renaming my downloaded pictures.

Comment: What downloaded image? From where? How are you getting it?